# Retrieve value from tuple by giving number or letter in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am very new to Haskell and am trying to retrieve 'a' if I give 0, 'b' if I give 1 and so on...

This is my code so far:

```
alpha = ['a'..'z']
numb = [0..25]

zippedChars = zip alpha numb
```

and this is the list: [image]

I want to make something like: getCharfromNumb, and if I type getCharfromNumb 0 I should receive 'a'.
And getNumbfromChar 'a' should give me 0.

Comment: What is your question about this?

Comment: Please do not use png files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```hs
import Data.List
import Data.Tuple

getCharFromNum :: Int -> Maybe Char
getCharFromNum n = lookup n $ swap <$> zippedChars

getNumFromChar :: Char -> Maybe Int
getNumFromChar c = lookup c zippedChars
```

See [Data.List.lookup](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:lookup), [Data.Tuple.swap](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Tuple.html#v:swap), and [Data.Functor.<$>](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--36--62-)